# Can I use PyInstaller from Python 2.7 to compile an executable for a Python 3 script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyinstaller

So, I tried installing PyInstaller in my Python 3.4 dir but, for some reason, I've been getting errors and I'm not able to install it. I however, do have a working PyInstaller in my Python 2.7 dir. I need to compile an executable for a Python 3 script. So I was wondering if PyInstaller from Python 2.7 can do that for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default version of [`PyInstaller`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyInstaller/2.1) only works with Python 2, so no, you cannot use it with a Python 3 script. However, there is an experimental version with Py3 support on [Github](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/tree/python3), so you can try that if you wish.

Comment: I just used PyInstaller from Python 2.7 and it worked. Well, first I ran into a problem with a missing package but once I downloaded the missing package required by the script, it compiled beautifully into an executable. And yes, the python script I turned into an executable was a Python 3 script. 
It works!