# Installing Pyinstaller

Tags: installation, pyinstaller

I am getting the below error while installing Pyinstaller. Pip is already installed and the command used at the Terminal is `pip install pyinstaller`.

> error: could not create
>   '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_dummy_thread': Permission denied
>
> Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/pq/l_flqbp91_xgfmb0j1x8ckyh0000gp/T/pip-install-PIu2W0/future/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record /private/var/folders/pq/l_flqbp91_xgfmb0j1x8ckyh0000gp/T/pip-record-7rrphN/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in
>   /private/var/folders/pq/l_flqbp91_xgfmb0j1x8ckyh0000gp/T/pip-install-PIu2W0/future/

My Python installed version is 3.6 and pip version is 10.0.1; however its showing some python 2.7 text in the output, as below, when I check versions:

```
Apples-MacBook-Pro:~ solelthermtechnik$ pip --version
pip 10.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-10.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip (python 2.7)
Apples-MacBook-Pro:~ solelthermtechnik$ python --version
Python 3.6.2
```

Please help to understand and fix. I could not get any way out of the question in [Can I use PyInstaller from Python 2.7 to compile an executable for a Python 3 script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31627677/can-i-use-pyinstaller-from-python-2-7-to-compile-an-executable-for-a-python-3-sc)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by trying to run with sudo (as admin) and password and it worked. So Pyinstaller successfully installed :)[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiqJ6.png)